# Is include path relative to current directory or source code location?

Tags: makefile, header-files

I am confused about makefiles searching the include paths.

Lets say I have a file structure:

```
.
├── hdrMainFolder.h
├── headers
│   └── hdrDifferentPath.h
├── makefile
├── sourceCode.cpp
└── src
    ├── hdrSamePath.h
    └── src1.cpp
```

I use `-I` option in the makefile to indicate the paths of the included headers.

Here are the included headers from src1.cpp

```
#include "hdrSamePath.h"
#include "hdrMainFolder.h"
#include "hdrDifferentPath.h"
```

Which of the paths I should indicate explicitly in the makefile? Which of them are unnecessary? Is it enough like below?

```
INCLUDING = -Isrc -Iheaders
```

Is it necessary to indicate to the path of a header, if it is only included by a source file under the same path?

Comment: The `-I` flag to your compiler has nothing to do with your makefile or make itself.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation about `-I` for your compiler? Have you tried not including the values and seeing what fails and then seeing which values fix the problem?

Comment: you will get much better results if you stop using make. Just compose script on your favorite scripting language calling compiler to build your app. if your codebase is small then make tool dependency tracking doesn't make sense: it is easier to rebuild whole project

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes sir, I tried reading the documentation but I am really confused. I didn't get where make searches for the paths. (I couldn't try the other option, since my makefile does not work yet. Complete newbie)

Comment: @lowtech: Thanks for the hint, but I need to learn how makefiles work.

Comment: @lowtech I disagree *wholeheartedly* rebuilding the entire project is never the right solution. There are plenty of alternatives to `make` if make itself is a burden (some of them are even fairly good).

Comment: make isn't searching for the paths when the `.cpp` files are compiled. The compiler is. make doesn't care about the header files unless you list them as prerequisites/targets in the makefile itself in which case *those* paths are relative to the current directory of the `make` process (same as the values of `-I` for the compiler process I believe actually).

Comment: @lulijeta use make -n to see what commands make will call. If you using make which don't understand -n option try to find the way to do 'dry run'.

Comment: @EtanReisner OK, If I understand correctly, make only tells the compiler to search the included paths in the given folders. Does make need to tell the compiler to search in the same path as the including source code? How about the same path as the makefile?

Comment: @Etan Reisner you disagreement doesn't have any rational basis for situation with small code base. My rationale is: if you have compilation time <20 sec then what the point to spend time to learn make?

Comment: make doesn't "tell" the compiler anything. It *runs* the compiler. If you give the compiler a `-I` flag then the *compiler* uses that `-I` flag to search for header files in additional locations. What relative path arguments to `-I` mean to your compiler is up to your compiler. I would expect, however, that most compilers will assume those paths are relative to the current working directory of the compiler process (which is, by default, the directory from which they were run).

Comment: @lowtech Because you won't always have a compilation time that is that short and because for projects that are that simple the requisite makefile is likely no more complicated then `target: source.o source1.o source2.o source3.o` and optionally `LDLIBS := -lsomelib -lotherlib` and `CFLAGS := -Wall ...`. That's it. And that gets you all the benefits of not unconditionally recompiling everything and a standard build process.

Answer (score 0):

```
Which of the paths I should indicate explicitly in the makefile? 
Which of them are unnecessary?
```

On the command shell, the directory where compilation instruction is being run is the current directory for the compiler.
[Compilation being done using direct command by user or using makefile]

The current directory (./) is default included by compiler for header file search paths.

If you create sub-directories and place your header files in sub-directory structure, then, you need to explicitly add `-I` rule for each sub-directory which contains the required header files.

```
hdrMainFolder.h -> present in current directory, no need to add -I rule for this  
hdrDifferentPath.h -> need to add -I rule (-I./headers)  
hdrSamePath.h -> need to add -I rule (-I./src)
```

[You may omit ./ in above added `-I` rules, I follow for better clarity]

```
Is it necessary to indicate to the path of a header, if it is only 
included by a source file under the same path?
```

Yes, source file location is not used to determine the user-defined header file search path. Need to explicitly mention it.